# Linking an HTML form to a SQLite database

Tags: php, html

Hello and thank you for taking the time to go through my issue.

I am trying to make a working newsletter form for my website which should store a person's name and email address in a database. I do not expect there to be much data to store, so I have - somewhat blindly - chosen `SQLite`.

My folder contains an HTML file, a PHP file and a SQLite database:

This is my **index.html** file:

```
<h1>Newsletter Signup</h1>
<form method="POST" action="./submit.php">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

This is my **submit.php** file:

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('mydb.db');

if (!$db) {
    die("Error connecting to database.");
}

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';

if (!$name || !$email) {
    die("Name and email are required.");
}

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)');

if (!$stmt) {
    die("Error preparing statement.");
}

$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

$result = $stmt->execute();

if (!$result) {
    die("Error executing statement.");
}

$db->close();

exit();

?>
```

The **mydb.db** SQLite database was created with the following lines of code:

```
CREATE TABLE subscribers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT
);
```

Whenever the 'Subscribe' button is clicked on, the following messages appear via DevTools in the console:

```
(In red) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1
(In yellow) VM491:161 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM491:161
```

and network > headers tabs:

```
Status: (failed)net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
Request Method: POST 
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

I have not been able to find a way to fix this problem. I am, of course, a newbie, and would sincerely appreciate your help, so please do go into details! Thank you once again.

Comment: What is the response of 405? What do you get while debugging?

Comment: What does your browser devtools show?  Did the POST really happen, and to the right URL? `action="./submit.php"` probably works but you can get rid of the `./` if the file is in the same dir as `index.html`.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Thank you for your reply. I have added the general headers and the response ones. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @NeilPeñaMartínez the error seems pretty forward, you don't accept POST

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for replying. I have updated the information above, I hope it helps!

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I have just noticed thanks to DevTools. Is there any other way to realize that is the case in VSC? Either way, would you kindly explain to me how I could accept POST? The website is currently being hosted locally.

Comment: If you have that much PHP warnings in the console, what did you try to resolve them?

Comment: @NicoHaase As far as I can tell, the errors are not factual, but might rather point to there being an underlying issue. I am banging rocks together here because I did not think I would need PHP for my HTML/CSS/JS project, which is a programming language I am ignorant of.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error` - how could a fatal error not be "factual"? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase While I am in over my head, what I am trying to accomplish should not be that hard, is that not right? I just hope somebody can point out my flaws so that I can resume my beginner project. Furthermore, I believe there is more to the errors than meets the eye because there IS a table named 'subscribers' in the same folder that contains both the HTML and PHP files.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - if there are such error messges, you need to resolve them. Start by dumping `$_POST` to see whether it contains the data it should contain

Comment: If you found an answer to your problem, please post it as an answer. Don't edit your question to contain the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for `enable_post_data_reading` variable is set to `on` in `php.ini` to verify is need to accept `POST`

If didn't work please comment in this answer and I'll glade to update my answer.

Comment: enable_post_data_reading = On in php.ini-development and php.ini-production and yet it only allows GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS. However, my installation may be faulty. If you were to redo your PHP installation, how would you proceed?

Comment: @NeilPeñaMartínez let me check if could be something else. If I update the answer I'll tag you. The error is still exactly the same? On what environment are your working? On debian I use LAMP as is, and in Windows I use Xampp or Wampp, default configuration should be enough to process a POST

Comment: @NeilPeñaMartínez by the way, you should change this in your php.ini file, not your development or production file. directly work with your php.ini if you can. I don't know your environment

Comment: @NeilPeñaMartínez you could also make a php file only with a phpinfo() command so you can read in that configuration file if enable_post_data_reading is enabled or not

Comment: Via phpinfo(): SQLite is in PATH // SQLite Library: 3.39.2 // sqlite3.defensive: On (local value), On (master value) // sqlite3.extension.dir: no value (local value), no value (master value) // enable_post_data_reading: On. Also, I added more information to the main text. I use Visual Studio Code's Code Runner and PHP Server. I hope this is useful information!

Comment: Thanks Leandro! For others - Firstly: use the Apache server on XAMPP, not the Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code. Second: set enable_post_data_reading On. Third: remove the commenting brackets before enable_post_data_reading and before extension=sqlite3. Fourth: move your project folder containing HTML, PHP, etc., to htdocs, a folder located in XAMPP. Fifth: if in doubt, check that sqlite3 and PHP are located in PATH. To do so, right click on the Windows button > system > Advanced system configuration > environment variables > click on Path > Edit user variables > new > filepath.

Comment: @NeilPeñaMartínez you are welcome ! I just wake up, sorry for not answer before. OMG what a nightmare! Im happy you can solve it! Yes, Xampp is a lot easir for devs situation, this things are configurated from the very begin